# Angular/Typescript doesn't execute for loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm fetching data with promise. I'm using this callback function to loop through the value.

```
selectedAppIdCalculator() {
this.fetchData2().then( value => {

  console.log("value: ", value);


  for (let app of value) {
    console.log("in for loop");
  }
});
}
```

The response value is not null, because it logs first the value. The value is a array with json objects.

But the for loop is never executed. Why?

In the debugging mode I noticed something weird.

[image]

The value is empty. Also the value in the log console is empty:
[image]

But when running normally it logs normally the response value. I'm really confused.

Comment: Could you post a sample of the content of `value` ?

Comment: don't use const type inside the for loop

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Please Note: you definitely _can_ use `const` in a for-of loop: `const value = ['a', 'b', 'c']; for (const app of value) { console.log(app); }`

Comment: @jozofe - the most likely issue is that `value` isn't an array... a common case would be where the array is deeper, i.e. `value.someCollection`. As Titian said, you need to share what is in `value` so we can answer the question.

Comment: @Fenton I edited my question

Comment: Is your `resolve` from `fetchData2` outside of the `promise`?? if so, it is being resolved before any data is available, it needs to be just outside the scope of the `for`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your resolve from `fetchData2` is outside of the `promise`. If so, `resolve` is called before any data is available and needs to be just outside the scope of the `for`.

This is because of the `async` nature, and your resolve completes before the request is complete and returns instead the initialised value of `reducedAppList`

Should look something like this:

```
for (const app of this.appList) {
   // logic ommitted
}
resolve(this.reducedAppList); // move inside the `.then(response => ....`
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok all your problem is that you dont wait the fetchAppData response before resolving.

You resolve your promise after 100ms with this.reduceAppList as an empty Array.
Later when fetchAppData response is received you populate this array.
Thats why the data are displayed in the console ( since the console use Object reference to display data ) and not in debug mode (since the breakpoint is set before populating the Array.

You should change the fetchData2 function to this :

```
fetchData2() {
   this.reducedAppList = [];
   this.httpService.fetchAppData().then(response => {
       this.appList = this.httpService.statistics;
       for (const app of this.appList) {
           if (app.appMailings !== null) {
               this.reducedAppList.push(app);
           }
       }
       return this.reducedAppList;
   });
}
```